# Are perfect graphs always invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Is it always the case that perfect graph is invertible? Also, is it any meaningful relation between inverse of a perfect graph and itself?

Thanks.

Comment: What is inverse of graph?

Comment: It is a graph defined by inverse of adjacency matrix of the original graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Graph of a single vertex is perfect and has singular ajacency matrix, though it could be an exception. However any cycle $C_{2k}$ (for $k > 1$) of even length is perfect and has singular adjacency matrix, too.